# Docker Wordpress keeps redirecting to online version of site

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker

I'm trying to set up docker wordpress as my dev environment on Ubuntu 17.10. I've made a copy of the db and placed it into the docker mysql service on port 8080 (using a wp plugin, which changes the home and site url)

[image]

I've arrived at the docker-compose.yml file below, but everytime I go to localhost:8000 or port 80 I get redirected to the original site online. I'm at a loss as to know what is wrong?

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootPword
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xyz_wp
      MYSQL_USER: xyz_2015
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: userPword

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      # generally need to use non-default values
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      # next line often not in tutorials - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46117771/issue-getting-docker-to-access-my-database-properly-with-wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: xyz_wp
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: xyz_2015
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: userPword
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: "af_"
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - /home/simon/code/wp_af2015/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootPword
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - db

volumes:
    db_data:
```

Comment: your wordpress is on port 8000 of the host and on port 80 of the wordpress container, according to `ports:
      - "8000:80"`

Comment: I don't completely understand but either way any localhost port is redirecting to www..... and that's what I need to change

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a little misunderstanding here.

when you add `:` after the domain it specifies the port.

From the Screenshot of PhpMyAdmin, it seems you set the Wordpress on port `8000`. Because after `:`, `8000` has been set.

From your docker file, there is a mistake, because from what you written, it is wrong.

The ports should be or `:80` or `:8000`, but not both.

If you want your docker to listen to `localhost port 8000` (your WP),
then on your docker config, you should set:

```
ports:
      - "8000"
```

Restart Docker, and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

A day later I tried to reach the dev site using an incognito window and everything worked! So the solve was to delete my browsing data from my normal browser. I do not understand what happened but the issue is fixed